# how to import data from a text file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read a text file as a pd `dataframe`, but i don't know which delimiter should i choose to read the data correctly.

[Data in the text file looks like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T1NZ.png)

> [image]

---

```
USAF   WBAN  STATIONNAME   CTRY ST CALL  LAT     LON      ELEV(M) BEGIN    END

007018 99999 WXPOD 7018                  +00.000 +000.000 +7018.0 20110309 20130730
```

I need to have `"STATIONNAME"` in one column but what i choose `delimiter = ' '` , data in that column will be separated each word in a column and all the data in the file will be messed up.

Any suggestion please !

Comment: Maybe [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622073/import-data-from-a-text-file-into-a-pandas-dataframe) can help you

Answer (score 1):

We can't tell for sure from the picture, but the data may be tab-delimited. If so, you can read the file like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('<filename>', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I solved the problem using  `pandas.read_fwf(path,compression='infer')`.
This command is used to read fixed-width-files.

We can also specify the header  `using pandas.read_fwf(path,compression='infer',names=header)`.